# Is the iPhone 4 antenna problem fixed in the iPhone 4S

Tags: iphone

Is the iPhone 4 antenna problem fixed in the iPhone 4S?

Was it secretly fixed for all new models or just the iPhone 4S or none?

Comment: Is "the problem" that people don't understand that there isn't a problem? As far as I can tell, iPhone 4 continue to be made, sold and used with the antenna design as originally launched. Am I misinformed?

Comment: @bmike, I agree. I don't know of any people that use their phone without a case or bumper guard - these folks wouldn't be affected by this "problem" at all.

Comment: Did you experience an actual problem or are you referring to the PR incident? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think so. Since Apple placed an extra antenna (now they are two) in the iPhone and they redesigned the whole antenna system (an extra receiver in the frame inter alia).

[image]

And according to the movies in [this blogpost](http://blog.gsmarena.com/iphone-4s-dual-antennas-solve-antennagate-issue-bumpers-no-longer-required-to-make-calls/), it seems like the new system did fix the so-called antennagate! They compared the iPhone 4S reception with an iPhone 4 which is suffering from the antennagate.

According to Apple itself, the system...

> Intelligently switches between two antennas to transmit and receive

Comment: lol I love how Apple just kinda of makes this huge bug fix a feature!

Comment: My Verizon iPhone 4 (MD146LL) has the 2nd antenna.